Are there any non-SI base units?
Are there any base units that are not in the SI system? If so why aren't they?
Edit: By this I don’t mean other systems that you can convert to (ie. Feet, Ounces, Hours, etc) I mean new base units with different quantities.

Gaussian or cgs units is the big one. Many others also arise when you start fixing fundamental constants (e.g., setting the speed of light to unity, $c=1$).

What is an inch or a foot?

@QPhysl that should be an answer

@DanielC, at least in the US, the customary units are legally defined in terms of SI units. For example, 1 inch is defined as 2.54 cm.

Why is this closed, there is only one question being asked

As @gandalf61 notes in their answer, the term "base unit" only makes sense as part of a coherent system of units, but if you are really asking if there are any units that cannot be converted to some combination of seconds, metres, kilograms, amperes, kelvin, moles, and candelas, then the answer is yes. Here are a few examples of units outside physics from Wikipedia and elsewhere:

letters and words: units used to measure the length of written texts.
currency (e.g. dollars, francs, yen, …): units of account measuring the market value of goods, services, and other items of financial value.
micromort: unit of risk defined as a one-in-a-million chance of death.
byte: unit of digital information that most commonly consists of eight bits.
Scoville heat unit: measures pepper hotness
dol: a unit equal a just-noticeable difference in pain

Coming back to physics, there are some quantities we measure that could have base units but don't because they are irrelevant for everyday life and industry.  For example, the SI system has a base unit for the flow of electric charge, but not for the flow of other conserved "charges" such as QCD colour, baryon number, and lepton number.


Are there any non-SI base units ?

There are obviously plenty of non-SI base units - but each one is part of some other system of units.
First you should note that a "base unit" does not exist in isolation - it is part of a system of base units, none of which can be expressed in terms of the others, and which are in turn used to construct other units in the system, known as "derived units".
For example, a second is not a base unit of time on its own. It only becomes a base unit once you include it in a system, which could be the SI system, the CGS system, the FPS system etc. And the units that are called "second" in each of these systems are technically distinct from one another because they could have different definitions.
You could even make up your own system of units, based on (for example) the fortnight as a base unit of time and the barleycorn as a base unit of length. But these base units would not be base units in isolation - they would be part of your made up system.
Since a base unit cannot float around unattached to a system, every base unit is either an SI base unit or a base unit in some other system. If you exclude non-SI base units then all the base units that are left are SI base units.

I only excluded ones you could convert to. I was wondering if there are any that you can’t convert to because they measure different things that SI doesn’t.
